# Where is the Mac Divx Web Player 7 cache folder?

Tags: macos, mac, cache, divx

Until recently, I was using Divx web player 1.4.2 because it seemed to be the least buggy. It was saving files in users/xxxxxx/movies/divx movies/temporary added files and was deleting them when the cache limit was reached.

Now with 7, it's saving them alright cause I can watch my HD space go down, but I can't find them. And it's not respecting the cache limit size (mine is 4GB).

The only way to clear up this space is a restart of the Mac. I'm running 10.6.8and Chrome. I've looked everywhere for the folder manually. Where is it?

Answer (score 1):

I hope you found a solution for this question before now but if you didn't here is how I found where the files are stored. I imagine you have Admin access to your account, or that the account you are using has "sudo" rights. If your account has "sudo" rights (which you can test by running the command below) this will find the things for you. The code below first changes into the root directory on your system and then runs the query to look for the mp4 files (for avi just replace mp4 with avi):

```
cd /
sudo find . -iname '*.mp4'
```

This should give you a full path for every mp4 file on your system. It is going to take a reasonable amount of time to go through the whole system. On my system, files were stored in one of the subdirectories of /private/var, so what you can do to make that 'find' command go a bit faster cd into '/private/var' instead of '/' in that first command above.

If you don't have sudo access, you can still run the command 2 but remove 'sudo'. It will go through directories again, but you will only have results for files that you have access to. You can also log in as Administrator user and run the commands above (without 'sudo', just 'find' portion).

I hope this helps you and others who have the same question.

Answer (score 0):

This may help:  there is a hidden folder called 'Library' which contains a lot of application files.  From the Finder menu bar, click on 'Go' then hit your option key.  The Library folder will appear in the list.  When you browse Library, there is a folder called 'Application Support' which may have a Divx folder containing your hidden files.

Answer (score 0):

I found it in mavericks in

```
/private/var/folders/sb/9tzlxs0n2jj3hf8d_6yxq03c0000gn/T/DDMCache
```

where the sb folder only had one folder in it, that really long String. The really long one has Folders C T and O in it. One way to found it is to use OmniDiskSweeper which scans the whole hard drive to find files by size.